# Mac OS X: How to launch an application (.app) from a "Command Line Tool" type of app?

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line

In Xcode 4.6, I created a new application based on the "Command Line Tool" project template.

How can I programmatically start another application (.app application bundle) from that "Command Line Tool" app?

Comment: You can use the `system(const char* command)` (included in stdlib.h) and run "open /path/to/application.app"

Comment: dont use system, the answer by NSGod looks good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this, using Launch Services and or `NSWorkspace`.

One of the more flexible ways to identity a bundled application is via its bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`), which is a string like `com.apple.TextEdit`. This allows you to identify an application without having to hard-code an assumed path where the application will be found, or by hard-coding the name of the application bundle, both of which a user could easily change. You can use `NSWorkspace`'s [`launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifier:) to launch the app. If you don't already know it, you can obtain the bundle identifier of an application bundle by checking its `AppName.app/Contents/Info.plist` file. Then use the following code:

```
if (![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
       launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.TextEdit"
                             options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
      additionalEventParamDescriptor:NULL
                    launchIdentifier:NULL]) {
      NSLog(@"launching app failed!);
}
```

Important: `NSWorkspace` is part of the `AppKit.framework` framework, which is not initially included in the "Command Line Tool" project template. To add it to your project, select the target in the list of targets like shown in the image below, and click the + button to add additional frameworks.

[image]

Add both `AppKit.framework` and `Cocoa.framework`.

That will result in all 3 being listed in the Link Binary With Libraries step. At that point, you can remove both the `Foundation.framework` and `AppKit.framework` from the linking stage, and leave just the `Cocoa.framework`, like below:

[image]

Comment: To use this kind of syntax ([[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]), what should I select for the Type option (C/C++/Core Data/Core Foundation/Core Services/Foundation) when creating a new "Command Line Tool" project?

Comment: @ytw: you can use the `Foundation` template, though you'll need to add the additional frameworks I mentioned. What template had you used (I had just assumed `Foundation`, sorry about that). If you're uncomfortable with Objective-C, let me know, and I can add code for using Launch Services (which will be C-based and is part of the CoreServices framework).

Comment: Thanks, NSGod.  The code you provided works fine most of the time.  One case it doesn't seem to work is when the Command Line app is started by launchd as root.  I see "launching app failed!" in a log file.  Any ideas what might have caused that?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried using the NSWorkspace approach and ran into a problem as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514259/macosx-launching-an-app-using-nsworkspace-from-a-daemon-doesnt-work-if-the-dae.  Can you please show me how to use Launch Services?  Thanks!

Comment: `launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:` is deprecated. You can use the new `openApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:` from `NSWorkspace`. It's easy to create an URL from an app bundle identifier by using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.TextEdit"]`. See Apple docu at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172700-openapplicationaturl

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried "open"? At least in terminal "open" runs files and/or apps.

Comment: "Open" works in Terminal, but how do I invoke open from code?